# How to confirm that swing is installed

Tags: java, swing, ubuntu-9.10

In Ubuntu 9.10 is there any way to confirm/ check if swing is installed and thus check its version!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Swing will be included in the JVM, if it's new enough.

See [this page](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/start/compile.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a JRE to run a desktop application, you can check for the 'java' executable in `$PATH`, look for `$JRE_HOME` or `$JAVA_HOME` environment variables.  Once a JRE is found use java -version to get its version.

If you are trying to deploy an applet, use the [Java Deployment Toolkit](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html#deplToolkit).

Answer (score 1):

Swing is included in the default Java JRE.  So just:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jre
```

If you need the JDK (to develop on), it's:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk
```

As far as the version, it should be compatible with Java 6.  You can check the exact package version with:

```
apt-cache show openjdk-6-jre
```

Comment: It is important to note that a JRE/JDK might be installed directly from the Sun/Oracle's site too.  In that case checking apt's meta-data might not help.

Comment: Sun's version is better. Use: `sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jre`  or  `sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jdk`

Comment: Chandru, that's a valid point.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the [Java installation page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/JavaInstallation) for Ubuntu that covers everything from SDK to web browsers.

Answer (score -1):

1. Open a terminal
2. Type: `java -version`

If it says something meaningful, you're fine; you have swing on that machine.

Comment: This is clearly not true.  For instance, he could have openjdk-6-jre-headless

Comment: I'm pretty sure he doesn't. Ubuntu 9.10 comes with out java at all. You install it by typing `sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jdk`  anyway, your observation makes sense and is still valid. Isn't this a superuser.com question anyway?

Comment: Most likely, he doesn't have a headless installation.  But it's best to make sure.  And yes, I almost voted to close it as belonging on Super User.